# is there way to get same result in es6 filter or lodash?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Trying to delete element from array based on settlementCode in rejectMessage array, I feel like this can be alot better with ES6 or lodash.

Can someone please help me to use that approach ?

data

```
const data = [
  {
        "drugName": "Metformin",
        "mailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": "N/A",
            "totalQuantity": "90.0",
            "rejectMessage": [{
                "settlementCode": "99",
                "settlementDesc": "Not Covered: Call us - System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card.||Sin cobertura: Llámenos - El sistema no pudo procesar su solicitud. Llame al número gratuito que figura en su tarjeta de identificación de beneficios."
            }]
        },
        "retailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": "N/A",
            "totalQuantity": "30.0"
        }
    },
    {
        "drugName": "CALCIUM",
        "mailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": "N/A",
            "totalQuantity": "90.0"
        },
        "retailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": "N/A",
            "totalQuantity": "30.0"
        }
    }
]
```

transform.js

```
    function transformPrice(drugPrice) {

          if (drugPrice.retailPrice.rejectMessage.length || drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage.length ){
            const retailRejecrMsg = drugPrice.retailPrice.rejectMessage;
            const mailRejectMsg = drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage;
            const retailErr = isErrorPresent(retailRejecrMsg);
            const mailErr =  isErrorPresent(mailRejectMsg);
          }

          if(retailErr){
            delete drugPrice.retailPrice;
          }

          if( mailErr){
            delete drugPrice.mailPrice;
          }

          return drugPrice;
        }

        function isErrorPresent (price) {
          const isError = function (element) {
            const bRet = checkErrorCodes(element);
            return (element.hasOwnProperty('settlementCodes') && bRet)
          }

          return price.some(isError);
        }

        function checkErrorCodes(el){
          let bRet = false;
          const errorCodes = [
            10015,
            2356,
            225,
            224,
              99
          ] 
          for (const err of errorCodes){

            if (err === ele.settlementCode){

              bRet = true;
            }
          }
           return bRet;
        }

transformPrice(data);
```

expected REsult

```
[{
    "drugName": "Metformin",
    "retailPrice": {
      "copayEmployer": "N/A",
      "totalQuantity": "30.0"
    }
  },
  {
    "drugName": "CALCIUM",
    "mailPrice": {
      "copayEmployer": "N/A",
      "totalQuantity": "90.0"
    },
    "retailPrice": {
      "copayEmployer": "N/A",
      "totalQuantity": "30.0"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: "I feel like in days of ES6 i wrote alot of code" .. are you posting from the future?

Comment: `_.remove` if you need an in-place removal, or `_.filter`/`.filter` if you can re-assign the array.

Comment: I'm not seeing any code that refers to the data.  Did you forget to post that code?

Comment: What is the expected output for this input? "*delete element from array based on settlementCode in rejectMessage array*" Based on what values exactly?

Comment: @adiga if settlementCode in the object matches errorCode i have in checkErrorCode metthod

Comment: @adiga added expected result, mailPrice is remove from one of the drug it contains error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean smth like this?

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

const drugPrice = data.map(item => {
  const errorCodes = [10015, 2356, 225, 224, 99];
  const f = ["mailPrice.rejectMessage", "retailPrice.rejectMessage"];

  f.forEach(path => {
    const rejectMsg = _.get(item, path);

    if (rejectMsg) {
      const y = path.split(".").shift();
      const hasCodeOrWrong = rejectMsg.find(i => {
        return !!~errorCodes.indexOf(+i.settlementCode)
            || !!~i.settlementDesc.indexOf(':');
      });

      hasCodeOrWrong && delete item[y];
    }
  });

  return item;
});
```

Comment: object would be something like this if drug either retail or mailPrice has rejectMessage array and it contains those errorCode that retail/mail price should be removed. `[
  {
  "drugName": "Metformin",
  "mailPrice": {
   "copayEmployer": "N/A",
   "totalQuantity": "90.0",
   "rejectMessage": [{
    "settlementCode": "99",
    "settlementDesc": "Not Covered: Call us -os."
   }]
  },
  "retailPrice": {
   "copayEmployer": "N/A",
   "totalQuantity": "30.0"
  }
 }
]`

Comment: @hussain, code above is working as you've described

Comment: is it possible to add another logic on top of this code `f the "settlementDesc" in rejectMessage, has a string without ":" , omit that entry of "rejectMessage"If all entries are omitted in the "rejectMessage", then remove the "rejectMessage" entry from the drug price response.`

Comment: @hussain, once again. You want to remove "settlementDesc" property in case it has no ":" inside. And remove "rejectMessage" property if it is empty array?

Comment: one correction i want to remove that rejectMessage object if settlementDesc is ":" that entry should be removed from rejectMessage array

Comment: @hussain, best practice says don't remove properties. Why you need that? You can set them to empty string always.

Comment: we dont want to send that object to frontend if object does not have value for the client , we are removing the object entry based on description

Comment: @hussain, updated. Change settlementDesc check if you need it to be present or not for removal

Comment: i will try to produce the result working on data , so this will remove complete entry settlementCode & settlementDesc from the rejectMessage